# ¿Como modificar la animación de un modal en ionic 2?

Tags: ionic, ionic2, modal

Quiero modificar la animación de un modal que tengo en una `view` en mi proyecto,  por defecto se anima desde la parte de abajo hacia arriba con un efecto de `fadein`, digamos que lo quiero es cambiar la animación de derecha a izquierda sin el efecto de `fadein` ¿Como hago esto?.

```
openCart(){
        var optionCarrito = {
            animation: 'slide-in-right'
        };
        let modal = this.modal.create(Carrito, null, optionCarrito);
        modal.present();
  }
```

Esto es lo que encuentro en la documentacion pero no se como puedo modificarlo

> NavOptions
>
> Some methods on NavController allow for customizing the current
>   transition. To do this, we can pass an object with the modified
>   properites.
>
> > **Property**    **Value**   **Description**
> >
> > animate           boolean     Whether or not the transition should animate.
> >
> > animation   string  What kind of animation should be used.
> >
> > direction   string  The conceptual direction the user is navigating. For example, is the user navigating forward, or back?
> >
> > duration    number  The length in milliseconds the animation should take.
> >
> > easing  string  The easing for the animation.
>
> The property 'animation' understands the following values:
>   md-transition, ios-transition and wp-transition.

Comment: Saludos Daniel, ¿Podrías colocar el código que has intentado por favor?